# numpy date "TypeError: must be str, not bytes" using python 3.4

Tags: numpy

this is my first Numpy program and I don't really see what I am doing wrong. I want to convert the date field from the csv from "2015-08-04 02:14:05.249392" to "2015-08-04". I don't really understand the error. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong please?

Here is the data

```
2015-08-04 2:14:05.249392,AA,0.0193103612,0.0193515212,0.0249713335,30.6542480634,30.7195875454,39.640763021,0.2131498442,29.0406746589,13524.5347810182,89,57,99
```

here is the code

```
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date,time

datefunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

a =  np.genfromtxt('/home/dave/Desktop/development/hvanal2016.csv',delimiter = ',',
               converters = {0:datefunc},dtype='object,str,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float',
               names = ["date","sym","20sd","10sd","5sd","hv20","hv10","hv5","2010hv","105hv","abshv","2010rank","105rank","absrank"])

print(a["date"])
print(a["sym"])
print(a["20sd"])
print(a["hv20"])
print(a["absrank"])
```

here is the error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/dave/3 9 15 my slope.py", line 13, in <module>
      names = 
     ["date","sym","20sd","10sd","5sd","hv20","hv10","hv5","2010hv","105hv","abshv","2010rank","105rank","absrank"])
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1691, 
in genfromtxt
   for (i, converter) in enumerate(converters)]))
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1691, 
in <listcomp>
    for (i, converter) in enumerate(converters)]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1690, 
 in <listcomp>
    rows = list(zip(*[[converter._loose_call(_r) for _r in 
  map(itemgetter(i), rows)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_iotools.py", line 
  657, in _loose_call
     return self.func(value)
   File "/home/dave/3 9 15 my slope.py", line 7, in <lambda>
      datefunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
 TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: While trying to solve the problem I used `StringIO` to simulate your input and therefore missed, what @donkopotamus found. But I then noticed a problem with `a["sym"]` not taking the string `AA`. Do you have the same issue with the actual file input through `genfromtxt`?

Comment: @roadrunner66 I do indeed. I was going to work on it tomorrow as I have run out of coffee and, being a true dullard, need all the help I can get. Thank you for looking at my initial problem but the splendid donkopotamus got it first time

Comment: Ok, then it's warranted for me to take another look. I'm interested since I use similar code all the time, but usually my stuff is more kludgy.

Comment: full disclosure I stole the code from an example MY code is too pathetic for words.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Hey there did you get anywhere with this? I'm getting unicodeDecodeError: "utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3:code point not in range(0x110000) none of the "solutions" I have found make any sense to me as they seem to be overly complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is probably that `np.genfromtxt` generates byte strings, not unicode strings.  Thus you must convert the incoming value to a `str` before parsing it as a date.

Something like the following should work:

```
datefunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: thanks @donkopotamus really great help got all the way to the last line of the csv and then it dumped out with this  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)

Comment: Are you using the correct `decode(<unicode type>)` for your file format?  Possibly you may have a weird terminating character in the file ... catch the exception and see what the text is ...

Comment: Hey there NOPE basic stupidity on my part! it's the print statement. I will try to get it sorted out as I have taken too much of your time. Thank you so much for your great help, I would NEVER have sorted it out without your guidance.